# how to connect to redis db with username and password nodejs node-redis

Tags: node.js, redis

How can i connect to a `Redis` db that has username and password?
below is the code example i'm trying to use, ( i'm using `nodejs` with `node-redis` and `Redis` version "redis": "^3.0.0",)

```
const client = redis.createClient({
  host: "localhost",
  port: 6379,
  password: "1234",
  username: "username"
});
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: Im not getting any error, but is this the correct way to implement this ? Pretty hard to find any documentation on this

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the version of Node Redis that you are using. Since it looks like you are using Node Redis 3.x it would look like this:

```js
const client = redis.createClient({
  host: "localhost",
  port: 6379,
  password: "1234",
  user: "username"
});
```

You could also connect using a connection string:

```js
const client = redis.createClient("redis://username:1234@localhost:6379");
```

Full documentation for 3.x is available on the [tagged branch](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/tree/v3.1.2) in the GitHub repo for Node Redis.

That said, I would recommend using Node Redis 4.x as it supports Promises, newer Redis commands, and many common Redis modules like RedisJSON and RediSearch.

To connect using 4.x:

```js
const client = redis.createClient({
  socket: {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 6379
  }
  password: "1234",
  username: "username"
});
```

or:

```js
const client = redis.createClient({ url: "redis://username:1234@localhost:6379" });
```

Details on connecting using Node Redis 4.x can be found in the [README](https://github.com/redis/node-redis) on the main branch of Node Redis and in the [Client Configuration Guide](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/docs/client-configuration.md).

Comment: if im using redis 3.x.x do i need to client.quit() ? is this necessary ? if i don't quit will it cause any errors?

Comment: I generally use `client.quit()` when I want to close a connection as it lets Redis know to dispose of the connection *and* closes it locally. I've run into problems when I just call `client.close()` where Redis doesn't know the connection is dead, and then I run out of connections. That said, for a Node.js app, I usually just keep one connection open, use it for everything, and call `client.quit()` when the process ends.

Comment: I do this will all Redis clients, regardless of language or version.

Answer (score 0):

To connect Nodejs Project with **Redis Version ^4.x**:

```html
const redisClient = redis.createClient({
  socket: {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 6379
  }
  password: "1234",
  username: "username"
});
redisClient.on("error", (error) => console.error(`Error : ${error}`));
redisClient.connect();
```

If you don't Provide socket, password or username then by default it will connection on **127.0.0.1:6379**

for by Default Connection use Beloved mention code

```html
const redisClient = redis.createClient();
redisClient.on("error", (error) => console.error(`Error : ${error}`));
redisClient.connect();
```

Redis Installation in system https://redis.io/docs/getting-started/installation/install-redis-on-windows/

For More information About redis as node package https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis

and For mode Redis Command https://redis.io/commands/